# How to run a python script from another python script and get the returned status code?

Tags: python, bash

I'm relatively new to both Python and bash. However, I am finding Python much more intuitive and easier than bash. I have a few bash scripts I have managed to cobble together, but I would like to replace them with Python scripts - for ease of maintenance etc.

The bash scripts essentially run python scripts, check the returned status code and act appropriately (e.g. log a message, fire off an email etc) - this is functionality that I thing I can for the most part, reproduce in a Python script.

The one thing I am not sure of how to do, is how to run a python script from another python script and get the returned status code.

Can anyone post a snippet here that will show how to run a small python script 'test.py' from a main python script 'master.py' and correctly retrieve the return code after running test.py from master.py?

Comment: You can always just import another python program (ie: having 'test.py' in the same directory as your running code, and calling: import test) to easily run secondary code, but it won't manage your return code business

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module

master.py

```
import subprocess
retcode = subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/python", "/path/to/test.py"])
print "Return code of test.py is ", retcode
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to look at the subprocess module in python. You can start another process using it, manipulate its streams and get the return code.